# Please fix my broken understanding of this simple thermocouple circuit

Tags: voltage, current, thermocouple, meter, divider

Here's my qualm:

As per the diagram, I can't understand how the trim probe (resistor) affects the meter reading for this thermocouple circuit.

[image: Circuit]

If I understand the diagram correctly, everything is connected in parallel.

For simplicity sake, the thermocouple at a given temperature (say 700°C)  could be represented as a voltage source. I could simplify and redraw the diagram as follows:

[image: simplified circuit]

As the temperature increases, let's say the thermocouple generates a steady 10 V for arguments sake (I know in reality it's much, much smaller). We can see there's 10 A going across our meter represented as a 1 Ω resistor.

[image]

If I take out the trim probe, surprise, the current doesn't change over the meter at all!

[image]

If the trim probe was in series with the meter, I could understand just fine how it might affect the reading. I'm sure I've grossly misunderstood something or everything and I look forward to learning something here.

Thank you for your time if you made it this far.